# Angular: can't apply a filter to data loaded via $http

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have some data being pulled in from an API in my controller with $http.get I then want to apply a text formatting filter to that text to make it all pretty.

However I am getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

all over my console.

**Here's the code:**

Controller $http get:

```
$http.get("url to my api data")
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.serviceStatus = data;

    })
    .error(function () {

    });
```

Filter within module:

```
app.filter('textFormat', function() {
    function format(input) {  
        // Call the passed in endpoint and at any capitalised letters, split it to have a space between words
        input = input.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ");

        // Get the character at index 0 and modify it to be uppercase. Then append the rest of the split string to the end
        input = input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.slice(1);

        return input;
    };

    format.$stateful = true;

    return format;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="services in serviceStatus">
    <p>The {{ services.service | textFormat }} is {{ services.status | textFormat }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: _I then want to apply a text formatting filter to that text to make it all pretty._ This is not what filter should do. This is a directive's job

Comment: That's because your filter is called in every watch and before $http.get could receive the data, it has been called multiple times already.

Comment: @AnandG - There is no DOM manipulation here. Only simple text formatting. A filter is perfect fit to be used in such scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this issue because of `$http` is an `async` call. It avoid from normal execution flow. You should change your filter code by below one

```
app.filter('textFormat', function() {
    function format(input) {  
     if(input) {  // Check if the value has been initialized
          // Call the passed in endpoint and at any capitalised letters, split it to have a space between words
          input = input.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ");

          // Get the character at index 0 and modify it to be uppercase. Then append the rest of the split string to the end
          input = input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.slice(1);

          return input;
       }
    };

    format.$stateful = true; // You can put these two lines in above code as well. 

    return format;
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Vineet that's sorted two Filters I was having problems with in one go! Upvote to you sir!

Answer (score 0):

You can not to use your filter function as a angular filter. The other solution is to place your filter function in your controller instead and then just call it from your view like this:

```html
<div ng-repeat="services in serviceStatus">
<p>The {{ services.service | filter:textFormat }} is {{ services.status | filter:textFormat }}</p>
</div>
```

Be sure that `textFormat` is the name of your function